# Is there a way to tranfer data from a function into a list?

Tags: python, list, function, append

I keep on trying to get the data from the function to display in the list, I've tried using `list.append` but I keep on getting errors, what am I doing wrong?

```
def pick_up():
        name=input("Good Afternoon, who would you like to pick up? ")
        additional_student=input(f"Is {name} the only person you want to pick up ?YES/NO")
        if additional_student == "Yes":
            print(f"Please wait, {name} would be with you shortly")
        else:
            name_2=input("Who else would you like to pick? ")
            print(f"Please wait, {name} and {name_2} would be with you shortly.")

pick = pick_up()
picked_students.append(pick)
print(picked_students)
pick_up()
```

Comment: Nothing is returned from the function, so `pick = pick_up()` makes `pick = None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pick_up()` function needs to return something.  Since it can return either one or two students, you probably want it to return a list of either one or two students, and `extend` your `picked_students` list with that list.

```
def pick_up():
    name=input("Good Afternoon, who would you like to pick up? ")
    additional_student=input(f"Is {name} the only person you want to pick up ?YES/NO")
    if additional_student == "Yes":
        print(f"Please wait, {name} would be with you shortly")
        return [name]
    
    name_2=input("Who else would you like to pick? ")
    print(f"Please wait, {name} and {name_2} would be with you shortly.")
    return [name, name_2]

picked_students = []
pick = pick_up()
picked_students.extend(pick)
print(picked_students)
```

Comment: Ik this is a weird request but could you edit your answer to match the edited question? So it would make sense. It kinda looks like you've answered the question with something else.

Comment: Fixed it so the question and answer match.